# How to set dual parameter of LinearSVC when PCA is applied before?

Tags: pca, svm, scikit-learn

I have a question concerning the use of the dual space in the cases of linearSVC classifier. Documentation advises to set dual = false when n_samples > n_features, and true otherwise.

In the particular case where n_features is highly > n_samples (82 instances for 55000 features, and when using  PCA in pipeline before linearSVC, should I consider the initial number of features or the number of features extracted by PCA to set correctly the dual criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Since the classifier learns on the projection done by the PCA, the number of features in in linearSVC is the number of features remaining after applying PCA.